# How to rotate a view from different angles?

Tags: android, boolean, android-animation, screen-orientation, android-orientation

I am trying to rotate an ImageButton by 180 degrees so it matches the reverse portrait orientation. When I did this the same way as the other orientation changes, the result was perfect, but not the animation.

```
 public void onOrientationChanged(int DeviceAngle) {
      float MyButtonCurrentAngle = MyButton.getRotation(); //Gets portrait rotation (0)
           if(DeviceAngle > 350 || DeviceAngle < 10) { //Portrait
                MyButton.animate().rotationBy(- MyButtonCurrentAngle).setDuration(100).start();
           } else if(DeviceAngle > 80 && DeviceAngle < 100) { //Reverse Landscape
                MyButton.animate().rotationBy(-90 - MyButtonCurrentAngle ).setDuration(100).start();
            } else if(DeviceAngle > 170 && DeviceAngle < 190) { //Reverse Portrait
                MyButton.animate().rotationBy(180 -  MyButtonCurrentAngle).setDuration(100).start();
           } else if(DeviceAngle > 260 && DeviceAngle < 280) { //Landscape
                MyButton.animate().rotationBy(90 - MyButtonCurrentAngle ).setDuration(100).start();
           }
```

I thought this happens, because the float MyButtonCurrentAngle gets MyButton rotation angle value (0 or not rotated) from the DeviceAngle between 350 and 10 (0 or 360, Portrait orientation) and uses it as a reference.

Even though I'm still doubting, I discarded the previous case. The float seemed to work well with the other orientations and I think the problem is the animation for the Reverse Portrait orientation. The button shouldn't be rotated by 180, but by either 90 or -90 degrees. This is because you can't rotate a device from Portrait to Reverse Portrait without going through either landscape option. (Can't rotate Portrait to Reverse Portrait directly).

After many unsuccessful attempts, I came to the conclusion that I can't use MyButton gotten angle value, after the button has been rotated and the orientation detected is either Landscape or Reverse Landscape. I thought about the creation of another float to get the Reverse Portrait MyButton angle value, but this activity's orientation is set to Portrait, so this doesn't make sense.

Therefore, I need to get MyButton rotation angle after it's been rotated with a float, using this values as a loop condition, and depending on the result, rotate it by 90 degrees or -90 degrees in two different animations. This was my latest approach to the issue:

```
    while (MyButtonCurrentAngle==90) { 
    if (DeviceAngle > 170 && DeviceAngle < 190) {
        MyButton.animate().rotationBy(90 - MyButtonCurrentAngle).setDuration(100).start();
    }
}
while (MyButtonCurrentAngle==270) { 
    if (DeviceAngle > 170 && DeviceAngle < 190) {
        MyButton.animate().rotationBy(-90 - MyButtonCurrentAngle).setDuration(100).start();
    }
}
```

Basically, this handles the device orientation from landscape and reverse landscape to reverse portrait. This didn't trigger any animation, so MyButtonCurrentAngle float angle value never changed or couldn't be detected? Why can't the if statements read it? I don't know and I would like to know what I am doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: post the xml, what are `MyButtonCurrentAngle` and `ButtonsAngle`

Comment: make sure code within `ifs` is reachable. try printing some logs inside both `ifs`

Comment: MyButtonCurrentAngle is an example of my buttons float that gets its current rotation value by getRotation. ButtonsAngle is onOrientationChanged int, none of them are in the xml file. Everything works perfectly and doesn't crash. The problem is that I want to a different animation for my buttons changing from 90 to 180 and from 270 to 180. (In other words, I want the change from landscape to reverse portrait and reverse landscape to reverse portrait to looks as good as its counterpart [portrait]).

Comment: are you sure that code within if is getting executed?

Comment: I am not sure, but I know that everything works perfectly until this reverse portrait issue I'm confronting now. (That includes animations and xml files, of course. Plus the app never crashes).

Comment: just try to print some log inside if statements and check whether they are printed or not

Comment: You need to run all animation on the graphics (ui?) thread (I cannot remember what the thread is actually called) if you don't no animation (except for methods that internally reference this thread IE rotateBy) will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

```
  OrientationEventListener OrientationEventListener = new OrientationEventListener(this, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI) {
        static final int DELTA = 20;

        @Override 
        public void onOrientationChanged(int Angle) {
            float AngleDestination = ButtonDestination;
            if (angle > 90 - DELTA && angle < 90 + DELTA) {
                AngleDestination = -90;
            } else if (Angle > 180 - DELTA && Angle < 180 + DELTA) {
                AngleDestination = 180;
            } else if (Angle > 270 - DELTA && Angle < 270 + DELTA) {
                AngleDestination = 90;
            } else if (Angle > 360 - DELTA || Angle < DELTA) {
                AngleDestination = 0;
            } 
            if (AngleDestination != ButtonDestination) {
                ButtonDestination = AngleDestination;
                MyButton.animate().rotation(ButtonDestination).setDuration(100).start(); 
            } 
        } 
    }; 
    orientationEventListener.enable();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you found that this code was running (either by break-point debugging or a Logcat statement) then try running the animation on the UI thread.

```
YourActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() 
        MyButton.animate().rotationBy(90 - MyButtonCurrentAngle).setDuration(100).start();
    }
});
```

You might also need to call start on that.

Comment: How would this solve my problem? The other animations do start. The problem is I can't check the button rotation angle value and give the adequate response.

Comment: So I guess i'm confused as to the problem. Re-reading - You are trying to rotate the image button, independent of screen orientation, by 180 degrees?

Comment: Yes, I edited it to explain myself better. It should not only depend on the orientation (Reverse Portrait), but also on the way it get to that orientation. Either from landscape, where the button is rotated by 90 degrees, or reverse landscape, where its rotated by -90 degrees from its original position.